# EF Core - Unable to query if entity.Name exists in List<string>

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Using **Entity Framework Core 3.1.7**

I have a table in the database containing Products.

```
public class Product 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I then want the user to be able to use a search field to find certain Products in a UI table.
When the query comes in I try to do the following:

```
var searchParameters = query.SearchParameters.ToLower().Split(' ', ',', '+').Distinct();

var result = _context.Products
                    .Where(p => searchParameters.Any()
                    && (searchParameters.Any(x => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(x)) //Version 1
                    ).ToList();
```

or an alternative

```
searchParameters.Any(x => EF.Functions.Like(p.Name, "%" + x + "%")) //Version 2
```

But however I tweak this seemingly simple thing I get:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(p => __searchParameters_0
> .Any(x => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(x)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

I realize the `.ToLower()` is going to be a problem so I wanted to run a LIKE statement for Case Insensitive search as for SQL Queries. But even so, the `List<string>` is not being translated.

Comment: Note that depending on your SQL Server settings, case insensitive matching may well be the default, so you need to do nothing for the search to be translated insenstively.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, thank you! I tried neglecting ToLower and it is able to find the results, but only if I fire one query per search parameters since the .Any doesn't translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) (or simulate the predicate builder parts), you can use an extension method to expand the `Any(`...`Contains)` expression into an "or" expression:

```
public static class LinqKitExt { // using LINQKit
    // keyFne - extract string key from row
    // searchTerms - IEnumerable<string> where one must be contained by a row's key
    // dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => keyFne(r).Contains(s)))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereContainsAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T,string>> keyFne, IEnumerable<string> searchTerms) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var s in searchTerms)
            pred = pred.Or(r => keyFne.Invoke(r).Contains(s));

        return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T,bool>>)pred.Expand());
    }
}
```

(And the 51 other variations of Where/OrderBy[Descending] Any/All Contains/StartsWith.)

Then you can use it like this

```
var result = _context.Products
                     .WhereContainsAny(r => r.Name, searchParameters)
                     .ToList();
```

PS Pursuing another answer, I realized that pulling the test to the caller eliminated most variations:

```
// searchTerms - IEnumerable<TKey> where all must be in a row's key
// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TKey>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<TKey> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TKey, bool>> testFne) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var s in searchTerms)
        pred = pred.Or(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

    return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T,bool>>)pred.Expand());
}
```

Then you just call:

```
var result = _context.Products
                     .WhereAny(searchParameters, (r,s) => r.Name.Contains(s))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you! I'm just curious, wasn't this behaviour enabled for Entity Framework (not Core) earlier? Either way, I'm sticking with the predicatebuilder for now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RKrogh I believe you may be correct, EF Core (even 5) has lost a lot of translations from EF 6 in pursuit of being more consistent (and often, less useful)...

Comment: @RKrogh FYI, I figured out a way to make it more generic by pulling the test to the caller; and also fixed a bug in the `ExpressionStarter` handling in the original answer

Comment: Nice! Thank you for looping back to me. I like the second version. Will check it out. What was the bug? I've been running it since you gave it and never noticed anything :)

Comment: @RKrogh By not using `var` with `pred`, the first call to `.Or` or `.And` did not realize it needed to remove the starter, and instead defaulted to `false` which works with `.Or` but fails with `.And`. (Basically the compiler calls the wrong version of the `.Or` or `.And` method.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I didn't realize it was of type ExpressionStrater but I see it now. Thank you for taking the time to get back to me about this!